# Parent does not have a default constructor. The default constructor must be explicitly defined

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-5, moq, mstest

I am writing unit test case to test Data Access Layer.

I am using Moq 4.7.10

I use EF5

Following is my code to create mock context

```
Mock<DbSet<T>> MockContextQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> data) where T : class
        {
            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>(); //this line doesnt create mock object of DBSet
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

            mockSet.Setup(x => x.Include(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockSet.Object);

            return mockSet;
        }
```

This is how I create use the above method

```
var sampleData = new List<foo>()
            {
                new foo()
                {
                URL = "https://www.bing.com",
                ID = 1,
                IsDeleted = false

            },
                new foo()
                {

                URL = "https://www.yahoo.com",
                ID = 2,
                IsDeleted = false

                }
            };

            var data = sampleData.AsQueryable();
            var mockSet = MockContextQuery(data);

dbContextMock.Setup(x => x.Foos).Returns(mockSet.Object); //this line throws error
```

I don't know whats wrong here.
Is it that the EF5 doesnt support mocking DBSet?

Edit: datacontext

```
public class MyDBContext: DbContext
    {
        public MyDBContext()
            : base("connectionstring")
        {}
```

Comment: Post the code for this Mock: dbContextMock. How does the constructor look like for this datatype?

Comment: I see the DBSet of EF 5 doesn't have any constructor. While DBSet of EF 6 has a default contructor.